# How to create a 2D array grid with empty values and a decreasing numbering system and input values from .txt file?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I have been given a task to code a grid with specifications and insert some data from a sample .txt file inside the multidimensional array.

I am having trouble with creating the grid by itself before putting sample data into it.

For the first row, I use a for loop to print out the first row of hexes.
And the bottom most for loop to print out the last row of hexes. So technically the 2D array in between the first and the last row of hexes are 9 rows by 12 columns 2D array. I've noted that but I just want to see whether it works for now, I will change the values in the `for` loop later.

And for the last row, i'm not sure how to print out the horizontal 0 - 8 which starts on what is supposed to be below the last row of hexes on the 3rd element to the 11th element.

This grid is supposed to be used to display some information given from a .txt file. I am just testing to see whether I can store the values from the .txt file into the 2D array as shown, then output the values given.

```
Sample .txt file: 
  [1, 1]-3-Big_City[1, 2]-3-Big_City[1, 3]-3-Big_City[2, 1]-3-Big_City
  [2, 2]-3-Big_City[2, 3]-3-Big_City[2, 7]-2-Mid_City[2, 8]-2-Mid_City
  [3, 1]-3-Big_City[3, 2]-3-Big_City[3, 3]-3-Big_City[3, 7]-2-Mid_City
  [3, 8]-2-Mid_City[7, 7]-1-Small_City
```

The coordinates in the text file represent the X and Y axis that reads from the horizontal axis, then the vertical axis.

The information inside the text file are separated by a delimiter '-'. The [1,1] represents the coordinates of where the value of the '3' (cityID) in the second column while the third column is the city name. But for now, the expected output is just the single digit from each '-' spacing at the coordinates stated in the .txt file.

I know my sample code DOES NOT print anything from the .txt file as of now. Because if I were to print out the string content, it would be everything from the .txt file. I am thinking of using vectors/stringstream and adding a delimiter to ignore the '-'.

```
ifstream fileName;
fileName.open("citylocation.txt");
string content;
getline(fileName, content); //this will read the file line by line

const int GridX = 12, GridY = 12;
int cityMap[GridX][GridY];

cout << " ";
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) //printing out the hexes on first row
    cout << " # ";
cout << endl;

for (int i = 1; i <=8; i++)
{
    cout << 8-i << " "; //printing out the number at side
    for (int j = 1; j < 12; j++)
    {

        cout << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

cout << " ";
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) //printing out the hexes on last row
    cout << " # ";
cout << endl;
```

Expected Results:

```
   # # # # # # # # # # #
 8 #     2 2           #
 7 #     2 2       1   #
 6 #                   #
 5 #                   #
 4 #                   #
 3 #   3 3 3           #
 2 #   3 3 3           #
 1 #   3 3 3           #
 0 #                   #
   # # # # # # # # # # #
     0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Actual Output :

```
     #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #
  8
  7
  6
  5
  4
  3
  2
  1
  0
    #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #
```

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you are asking. Your expected results is just spaces. But you are explicitly stream the array you just put zeros into to out. Do you want numbers or spaces?

Comment: You expect no zeroes in the output, so why do you print them, then?

Comment: Just spaces, guys. I just explicitly stream the zeroes because if I didn't, it would result in a stream of negative numbers in the output.

Comment: That's because you'd be printing uninitialized contents of `cityMap`. Just print a space instead, for the time being, so you get the grid borders right. You also print one too many space around each `#`. Is this an exercise, btw?

Comment: Did you mean `int i = 9; i>=0; i--`?  You wrote `i <= 0` but you likely meant `i >= 0`.  The loop should continue while `i` is positive.

Comment: It's reasonable to control the loop with one counter `i` that goes from from 0 to 9, and then compute a second value within the body of the loop that is `9 - i`.  Which will be a counter that effectively simultaneously counts from 9 to 0.

Comment: Now you've changed the question my answer looks silly. For clarity, you do care about the stars being in the right place, and now understand how to make the numbers run down?

Comment: @jrok right i got it! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the question of whether you want numbers or spaces, the need for a decreasing number sequence using a number sequence that increases, you have this in the middle:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++)
{
    cout << i << " "; //printing out the number at side
    // other stuff in between using i
    cout << endl;
}
```

giving the numbers 1, 2, 3, .... 11.

Of note, `12 - i` for each of these gives 11, 10, 9, ... 1.
The minus i makes it decrease instead of increase.

(This isn't precisely what you need in the end, because of the edges, which are hinting at by some loops going to 11 and some to 12 in your code).

```
for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++)
{
    cout << 12 - i << " "; //printing out decreasing numbers at side
    // other stuff in between using i, which is unchanged
    cout << endl;
}
```

Having 12 twice might make it inflexible - a `const` number might be worth considering.